# How to specify a version of JDK on windows7?

Tags: java, version, environment

The thing is i have jdk1.6.0_45, jdk1.7.0_09 installed on my computer.
Normally i use JDK7 as my work environment with following system variable setting:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09;
classpath=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

And when i execute `java -version` in cmd, it displays the version correctly:

```
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Here i encounter a problem, i need to switch to JDK6 for another project. So i changed system variable `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`, i supposed that it should works for the new setting. But actually not, when i executed `java -version`, it still shows the currently using jdk is 1.7.0_09.

Is this alright?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but have you closed and opened new console after changes?

Comment: Yes i did. Anyway, thanks for replying. Finally i found what the problem is. There is a java.exe(which is jdk7) under system32 folder. The full path system variable is `path=C:\Windows\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`. Which means the unexpected java7 will always be the selected version on my computer even i have specified another version(like jdk6). It might came along with some browser plugin/applet. When i removed this java.exe, everything goes fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set path for Jre 6 when jre 7 installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131940/how-to-set-path-for-jre-6-when-jre-7-installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found what the problem is. 
There is a java.exe(which is jdk7) under system32 folder. 
The full `path` system variable is `path=C:\Windows\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`. Which means the unexpected java7 will always be the selected version on my computer even i have specified another version(like jdk6). It might came along with some browser plugin/applet. When i removed this java.exe, everything goes fine.