# Where is sonar directory?

Tags: java

What is sonar? where is the sonar directory? I need to located conf/wrapper.config in sonar directory to change the wrapper command from JRE7 to JRE6. But where can I locate the path?

This is the explanation from user -> rsingh25:-
refer to conf\wrapper.conf in Sonar directory, by default it has wrapper.java.command=java

To fix this, change following property of the "wrapper.conf" file wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_XX\bin\java

references link:- [How to set path for Jre 6 when jre 7 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131940/how-to-set-path-for-jre-6-when-jre-7-installed)

Comment: This is sonar... http://www.sonarqube.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonar is a code analysis tool for java. Rsingh25 's answer was probably specific for someone using sonar and have trouble using the right JRE. If you're not using sonar, then his answer is not going to help you very much.