# Getting different version for java and javac

Tags: java

Before marking it duplicate FYI I have already read [How can I change the Java Runtime Version on Windows (7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333553/how-can-i-change-the-java-runtime-version-on-windows-7) and [How to set path for Jre 6 when jre 7 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131940/how-to-set-path-for-jre-6-when-jre-7-installed).

I have both Java7 and Java8 in my machine. I have

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60
PATH = ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;....
```

but I am getting

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

C:\>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_60
```

I want to set JRE to 1.7 too. How to do that?

Comment: JRE 1.8 must be somewhere on the PATH before JDK 1.7. Type `echo %PATH%` and look through directories that are there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You will probably have to edit your *path* environment variable.

If you want to check what's in your PATH environment variable in an organized fashion, run:

```
echo %path:;=&echo.%
```

Make sure the *1.8* is not on the path or if you want it there make sure it appears after *1.7*.

To edit it, go to `My Computer > Properties > System Properties > Advanced tab > Advanced section > Environment Variables`.

Also check what is actually launched when you run `java` from the command line, run the following command:

```
where java
```

It will show you what windows runs when you request *java*.

Comment: 1.8 is not in path at all. PATH has entry for 1.7 only.

Comment: Ahaa - I see there is an shortcut entry C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe pointing to 8. Does anyone know what this entry in path for? If not important I am planning to delete this entry or move to the end.

Comment: I'd rename it first to `java.exe.bak`, an see if it breaks anything.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, remove or change the name of java.exe and javaw.exe into System32 folder:

[image: Like this screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the System Variable's `Path` with JRE bin's path.

Answer (score 0):

where java did work for me. I found there is another version of java associated with the SPSS (1.8.0). Uninstall SPSS and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was:
In "Path" variable replace "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;" with %JAVA_HOME%\bin where JAVA_HOME variable was set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60"